# Jquery Text editor

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, rich-text-editor

I have recently decided to use the jQuery text editor. However, I am confused when I access the `textarea` on which I am using the jqte the textarea shows no data.

```
                             <!DOCTYPE html>
              <html>
              <head>
               <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge,chrome=1">
              <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
           <title>jQuery TE | Downloaded Demo | v.1.3.6</title>

  <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="demo.css">
  <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="../jquery-te-1.3.6.css">

<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery.min.js" charset="utf-8"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="../jquery-te-1.3.6.min.js" charset="utf-8"></script>
 </head>

<body>
 <h1>jQuery TE</h1>

<div class="navigation">
<a href="http://jqueryte.com" target="_blank">Home</a>
<a href="http://jqueryte.com/demos" target="_blank">Demos</a>
<a href="http://jqueryte.com/documentation" target="_blank">Documentation</a>
<a href="http://jqueryte.com/comments" target="_blank">Comments</a>
<a href="http://jqueryte.com/about" target="_blank">About</a>
<a href="http://jqueryte.com/license" target="_blank">License</a>
</div>

<h2>Demo | v.1.3.6</h2>


  <!------------------------------------------------------------ jQUERY TEXT EDITOR  

 <textarea  cols="2" rows="3" name="textarea" class="jqte-test"  id="mytextarea"><b>My      contents are from <u><span style="color:rgb(0, 148, 133);">TEXTAREA</span></u></b></textarea>

<p>
<button class="status">Toggle jQTE</button>
</p>
<hr>

<input name="input" type="text" value="<b>My contents are from <u><span style=&   quot;color:rgb(0, 148, 133);&quot;>INPUT</span></u></b>" class="jqte-test"/>

  <div name="div" class="jqte-test"><b>My contents are from <u><span style="color:rgb(0, 148, 133);">DIV</span></u></b></div>

   <script>
  $('.jqte-test').jqte();

 // settings of status
 var jqteStatus = true;
  $("textarea#mytextarea").bind(function(){ alert($(this).html()) ;});
 $(".status").click(function()
 {
    jqteStatus = jqteStatus ? false : true;
    $('.jqte-test:first').jqte({"status" : jqteStatus})
  });
 </script>
```

I am actually checking how should I get the jqte formated html? There are no comprehensive notes on it. Can someone help me?

Comment: I have added the full code. i am still unable to get the html from the jqte..

Answer (score 6):

The actual editor window is a div with the class "jqte_editor".

And so...

```
$(".jqte_editor").html()
```

... will give you the latest/edited content.

Comment: But what if there is more than one `jqte` on the page?

Comment: @Pow-Ian (part 1 of 2): The method I used for discovering the above technique is worth utilizing for this and other coding, as well — that is, the browser developer tools to learn more about the elements on the page (e.g., "Inspect element" in Chrome's right-click context menu). By using that technique, you would be able to see whether the multiple editor elements were uniquely identified in any manner.

Comment: @Pow-Ian (part 2 of 2): If not, then look for a unique identifier for the parent element(s), and then find the contained div for the editor. For instance: $("#parentElementID").find(".jqte_editor"). If you'll be frequently referencing it, make it a jQuery object, so that you're not searching for it each time.

Comment: Well internally the plugin uses `closest` and matches the jqte class or the one provided. So internally when setting the value the author of the plugin recognized there needed to be a way to set the value for multiple `jqte` constructs but for whatever reason did not do the same for a getter. It feels off that you would need to add an extra wrapper in order to have access to multiple editors, but it is also a perfectly valid way to do it.

Answer (score 3):

Use

```
$("textarea").html()
```

instead of `val()`, because it's more secure, it will escape special chars and will prevent Xss attacks

[jQuery html() method](http://api.jquery.com/html/?rdfrom=http://docs.jquery.com/mw/index.php?title=Html&redirect=no#html1)

nevertheless, if you need to display input text as "live" you can use .val() method

Comment: I have added the full code. i am still unable to get the html from the jqte.please check the edited question.

Comment: This thing is confusing... actually where the typing goes.. I don't see the value change of the textarea.

Comment: Ok that is what I want but it is not working like this in the browser.. What did you do out there?

Comment: ;) hehe great! have a nice day!

Answer (score 3):

I had this same problem and here is what I did to solve it.

I noticed the plugin had a setter but not a getter equivalent for the value of the editor; this is odd because the normal jQuery pattern for plugins that create content with a value is to have the getter be an overloaded paramater-less version of the setter.

So I looked in the plugin code and made this modification. From the uncompressed version of the code:

This:

```
$.fn.jqteVal = function(value){
   $(this).closest("."+vars.css).find("."+vars.css+"_editor").html(value);      
}
```

Changed to:

```
$.fn.jqteVal = function(value){
    if(typeof value === 'undefined'){
        return $(this).closest("."+vars.css).find("."+vars.css+"_editor").html();
    }else{
        $(this).closest("."+vars.css).find("."+vars.css+"_editor").html(value);
    }
}
```

And from the 'minified' version:

This:

```
e.fn.jqteVal=function(t){e(this).closest("."+u.css).find("."+u.css+"_editor").html(t);}
```

Changed to:

```
e.fn.jqteVal=function(t){if(typeof t === 'undefined'){return e(this).closest("."+u.css).find("."+u.css+"_editor").html();}else{e(this).closest("."+u.css).find("."+u.css+"_editor").html(t);}}
```

After making the change you can now use the `jqteVal()` function like any other jQuery value function:

```
$(SELECTOR).jqteVal("text that goes into editor"); //Setter
var editor_value =     $(SELECTOR).jqteVal();      //Getter
```

I am not sure why the author did not do this but I have had a lot of success with this methodology.

Comment: spot on! i guess the original project has kind of fizzled out (due for an update)? but continues to live on regardless. could probably do with a move to github or similar

Answer (score 2):

Use this as said in documentation:

```
$(".editor").jqteVal("New article!");
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe using val() instead of text():

```
 window.setInterval (function(){alert($("textarea").val());},3000);
```

Comment: I have added the full code. i am still unable to get the html from the jqte. check the edited question.

Answer (score 0):

if you have a textarea of id "MYTEXTAREA"

you would access it like

```
window.setInterval (function(){alert($("textarea#MYTEXTAREA").val());},3000);
```

Comment: I have added the full code. i am still unable to get the html from the jqte

Answer (score 0):

> make textarea a text editor

```
$("#textareaID").jqte();
```

> and to read the data

```
var text = $("#textareaID").text();
```

> or

```
alert($("#textareaID").text());
```

Comment: I have added the full code. i am still unable to get the html from the jqte

Comment: I read somewhere that the use of jqte is very straight forward. but this is very complicated. lol

Answer (score 0):

i would use an change event instead of timeout.

```
$('#textareaID').bind('input propertychange', function() {
//...
});
```

and use .html() instead of .text() to see the html formatting. 
or replace all \n to < b r  /> (without spaces)

Comment: I have added the full code. i am still unable to get the html from the jqte. please check the edited question.

Answer (score 0):

Add this code to your script.

```
$('.jqte-test').on("keyup", function(){
        var content = $(this).html();
        $(this).parent('.jqte-test').find('textarea').val(content);
    });
```

So you can get required out put at the **textarea** itself.

Answer (score 0):

maybe i am too late but i was looking for a solution too without changing the original css as some pages i want it default and some i wanted a custom size. simplly set inline css after the plugin js. something like this.

```
$('.te_editor').jqte({
});

<style>
.jqte_editor{height:350px;max-height:500px;}
</style>
```